# Javascript can't get content of element

Tags: javascript

I've written code using Javascript to format the following section of a webpage based on the values:

```
<div class="col-md-auto mx-auto">
        <h3>Average price</h3>
        <p id="avgPrice"></p>
        <br>
        <div>Average change</div>
        <div class="change" id = "avgChange"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-auto mx-auto">
        <h3>Max price</h3>
        <p id="maxPrice"></p>
        <br>
        <div>Max change</div>
        <div class="change" id="maxChange"></div>
      </div>
```

(The values for the text within each of the id's are getting pulled from a database, and appear correctly on the webpage when I start the server)

Here is my Javascript to format the HTML based on positive/negative values:

```
function changeFormatter() {


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var change = elements[i]; //this is where the problem is
    console.log(change);
    if (change > 0) {
      elements[i].innerHTML = "▴ " + change + "%";
      elements[i].classList.add("text-success");
    }
    if (change < 0) {
      elements[i].innerHTML = "▾ " + change + "%";
      elements[i].classList.add("text-danger");
    }
  }
}
```

This code is being called by the following eventlistener:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  getData(); //gets values from database and adds them to HMTL
  changeFormatter();
});
```

The issue is the line where I'm defining the var change. The output of the console.log on the line below it shows the text I want is there, see image below:

But no matter what I try I cannot get the text contained within this div. I've tried elements[i].value, .textContent, .innerHTML, .innerText, parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML)... but they all return 'undefined' when I try and log them. I would really appreciate any suggestions!

[image]

[image]

Output of console.log(elements[i], elements[i].innerHTML)
[image]

Comment: try this: `var change = Number(elements[i].innerHTML || 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this however it logs '0' for each value instead of the values from the first screenshot

Comment: can you share the value of this: `console.log(elements[i], elements[i].innerHTML)`

Comment: How do you call the function? Please update your question using the snippet function to make a [mcve]

Comment: this is how you want it to work, i assume boldly: https://jsfiddle.net/k8xnrgza/ if you keep getting 0, it means `changeFormatter` is getting called, before the `.change` values are set

Comment: `Output of console.log(elements[i], elements[i].innerHTML)` image is some voodoo right there. can't figure it out based on the code provided

Comment: Is `getData()` making an AJAX call?

Comment: But if it was the case that the changeFormatter function was getting called before the values are being set, the console.log I'm calling from within that function would show the divs as being empty I thought?

Comment: can you also share the code of getData() ? i think @j08691 is on to something

Comment: Sure I'll update the question to include that

Comment: @paulf all and all sounds like changeFormatter is getting called too soon. if there is a callback functionality in `getData` call it there. If there isn't try calling it in a timeout `setTimeout(() => changeFormatter(), 0)`

Comment: Issue is solved now, you were both correct regarding the function getting called too soon. I moved the call for changeFormatter to inside getData() and can now access the data inside the div without any problem. Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate the effort! The fact that the values were appearing correctly inside the HTML output by console.log, but weren't accessible, really confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.innerHTML should be correct as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/awLynp28/3/. All I did was copy your script, have it run on page load (since it looks like you have something like that in there, I am assuming your function is getting called after the data is fully called in), and change
**var change = parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var change = parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML); //this is where I put innerHTML
    console.log(change);
    if (change > 0) {
      elements[i].innerHTML = "▴ " + change + "%";
      elements[i].classList.add("text-success");
    }
    if (change < 0) {
      elements[i].innerHTML = "▾ " + change + "%";
      elements[i].classList.add("text-danger");
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: If you get NaN after running this, then your data might not be loaded in fully before you are running changeFormatter(). If that is the case, try calling changeFormatter at the end of your getData() function instead of in the event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this jsFiddle proved that the changeFormatter function was getting called too early in my own code